# Grep Line break in Indesign software

Tags: grep

does GREP in indesign can help to break the line

Example: (below is the formate i want grep help me to break line from complimentary & of equal) is that possible?

```
You and your guest are invited to enjoy one complimentary
MAIN COURSE when a MAIN COURSE
of equal or greater value is purchased.
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about programming.

Comment: The output should be?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, and you have one long line as follows:

```
You and your guest are invited to enjoy one complimentary MAIN COURSE when a MAIN COURSE of equal or greater value is purchased.
```

You want to break that long line into the following 3-lines:

```
You and your guest are invited to enjoy one complimentary
MAIN COURSE when a MAIN COURSE
of equal or greater value is purchased.
```

Then `sed` is what you want, not `grep`:

```
sed -e 's/COURSE\sof/COURSE\nof/' -e 's/complimentary\s/complimentary\n/'
```

Usage:

```
sed -e ... -e ... <<<"Your long line"
```

or

```
echo "Your long line" | sed -e ... -e ...
```

**where** `...` are expression(s) 1 and 2 above (e.g. `'s/COURSE\sof/COURSE\nof/'`)